# Forms Authentication: How to change the Username using LINq

Tags: c#, authentication

I have a system whereby an administrator enters in the IT credentials for users who use the system.
Included in this is the Username for that person.
However if she makes a mistake, I am not sure how she can correct it.
I am using Forms Authentication, MVC and Entity Framework 4.0.
I am using the aspnetdb database supplied by Microsoft with the User credentials.

One possible solution is to delete and then create the user with the new username. But the problem then is that I lose the password.

Should I create a model of the database in EF so I can modify the database, or should I try something else like stored procedures?

Comment: Are you using MemberShip? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx

Comment: I am using Membership. I have not found a way in which you can use it to change the username.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the easiest will be to create a stored procedure that will update just the **UserName** field in **aspnet_Users** table

Comment: Yes. Another SO question points me to http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/070109-1.aspx#postadlink which shows me how to do this.